# Link from the menubar is not being clicked but perfectly working on pc as navbar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I copied this code from somewhere else and don't know what to link on it are as all option are being shown in menu bar but the only problem is link aren't opening.

```
<header class="site-navbar py-4 js-sticky-header site-navbar-target" role="banner">
    <div class="mr-auto">
        <nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right" role="navigation">
            <ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-link text-left">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="about.html" class="nav-link text-left">About Us</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="teachers.html">Our Teachers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">Our School</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="admissions.html" class="nav-link text-left">Admissions</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="courses.html" class="nav-link text-left">Courses</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link text-left">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-auto">
        <div class="social-wrap">
            <a href="#"><span class="icon-facebook"></span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="icon-twitter"></span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="icon-linkedin"></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="d-inline-block d-lg-none site-menu-toggle js-menu-toggle text-black"><span
                    class="icon-menu h3"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Are you saying that `<a href="contact.html"` etc. are not working? Or only those `<a href="#"` links? Do you have  javascript in place that handles those "menu-toggle" links?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the files with the name `about.html`, `admissions.html`, `courses.html`, `contact.html`?
Just make sure you have created the files within the same directory